# unable to open file (in target "iRSS WatchKit Extension" in project "iRSS"): Error when building

Tags: swift, cocoapods

When trying to Run/Build my project (with CocoaPods installed), I get the following error:

```
error: /Users/griffin/Desktop/iRSS/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods iRSS WatchKit Extension/Pods-iRSS WatchKit Extension.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "iRSS WatchKit Extension" in project "iRSS") (in target 'iRSS WatchKit Extension')
```

I have tried running `pod clean` and `pod deintegrate`, but the error is still there!

Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: did you find solution?